# WSO2 ESB Application Server installation ISSUE

Tags: wso2, esb

i'm new of WSO2 ESB. I installed the 4.7.0 version. I'm trying my first approach to RESTFul Web Services developed using CXF framework. I want to publish a first Hello World example. I downloaded and installed the WSO2 dev studio for eclipse Juno. I had to install the application server feature. So from the configuration tab in the ESB GUI i selected the "features" link, clicked on the "find features" button and then selected Application Server.

The installation worked fine. But when i try to run a web service through the "Find Service" link i GET the 404 Status error from Tomcat 7... telling me that resource was not found.

 Did i miss something? what's wrong in the installation procedure?

thanks a lot.

PS the service works fine on the WSAS stand alone 5.1.0

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deploy RESTFul Web Services developed using CXF framework, you have to define the required environment (CXF) in `repository/conf/tomcat/webapp-classloading.xml` (Note: this will be available after you install the AS features in to the ESB) or with in the app (`META-INF/webapp-classloading.xml`).

Also the required resources (jars) should be located in `${carbon.home}/lib/runtimes`. In the default ESB 4.7 distribution the CXF related resources are not in this location. So as a solution you can copy the directory `${carbon.home}/lib/runtimes/cxf` of the AS 5.1.0 distribution into the `${carbon.home}/lib/runtimes` of ESB 4.7. You have to create a folder name `runtimes` inside the `lib` folder.

Comment: thanks a lot... can i develop restful web service using jersey framework too?

Comment: WSO2 AS supports JAX-RS (311) , therefore it should be possible to do that.